# Heap height includes root level

Tags: heap

**Is heap root, included in count of heap height?**

Heap height should represent number of levels of the heap structure.
According to formulas

- MIN number of elements = 2 power (h-1) ,
- MAX number of elements = 2 power h -1

root level is counted to heap height. Although, I found some descriptions where that's not the case.
-Q= I'm interested if there is any **rule when root shouldn't be included
to count of the heap height**.

Also, I already found the answer that in heap, if both children have same value, and parent element should be swapped, it is safe to swap it by either (there is no preference left/right child). Can someone confirm this, so I can completely discard any doubts.

UPDATE:
According to definition of the [height](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/height.html) , height of the root is 0, then  correct formulas for min and max number of elements are:

- MIN=2 power h
- MAX=number of elements = 2 power (h+1) -1.

Officially by definition of the tree height **root level isn't included in the height count**. Thanks trincot for help with resolving this doubt.
Although this is correct way to address heap height, there might be some resources online that include root level to the height count (which is wrong by official definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a heap data structure is a tree with specific properties (specifically, it is a rooted, complete, binary tree, whose values obey the heap property), the definition of the *height* of a heap is the same as the definition of the height of a rooted tree.

Wikipedia defines it [as follows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology):

> The **height** of a node is the length of the longest downward path to a leaf from that node. The height of the root is the height of the tree. [...] a tree with only a single node (hence both a root and leaf) has depth and height zero. Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are allowed) has height −1.

With this definition the height of a tree is one less than the number of *levels* in a tree.

Almost always this is the definition used. But in rare cases you'll find a definition where the height is the number of levels. For instance [here](https://www.includehelp.com/data-structure-tutorial/find-height-maximum-depth-of-a-binary-search-tree.aspx). But this is a less popular definition.

Here is an argument in defence of the more popular definition:

Imagine the tree to be a pieced together set of ropes, each piece of rope having the same size (e.g. 10cm), and the places where the ends are tied together, are the vertices. Now pick up the "root" and hold it high up in the air. The ropes all hang vertically, all forming one vertical column. Now measure the distance from the root to the lowest point of this hanging structure: that is physically what we would call the height of that structure. It is the sum of lengths of the little connected ropes that form the longest path. This corresponds with the popular definition (as on Wikipedia) of a tree's height. It depends on the number of *edges* of the longest path, not on the number of *nodes* on that path.

---

As to your other question: yes, if a parent should sift down the heap, and both children have the same value, then it is safe to swap it by either.